# Why does Riemann-Roch theorem implies the following characterization of $\Omega^2(D)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading this [article](http://libgen.org/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1007%2Fbf02568416) and I didn't understand this part in the second page of the second chapter:

[image]

Why this is true using Riemann-Roch theorem? ($D\doteqdot \inf\{\text{div}(\omega_{g-1}),\text{div}(\omega_g)\}$.

My only background in Algebraic Geometry is Fulton's algebraic curves book, I need help!

Thanks in advance.